# How can i get user list of all the orders place in Magento2 using rest api

Tags: rest-api, magento2.2.4

In Magento2 How can i get the list of orders placed by specific user using REST API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://yourdomain/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=customer_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=2&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq

OK, so what is this?

The endpoint for getting orders is: http://yourdomain/rest/V1/orders

Make sure you change "yourdomain" to your actual domain.

This endpoint is reached by GET.

Next, the so called `searchCriteria` is a mandatory field to send to this endpoint.

So, the rest of the URL pretty much sets

- filter groups: [filterGroups][0] means this is the filterGroup with id 0, i.e. the first one
- filters: [filters][0] means this is the first filter within the filterGroup
- and for each filter we set [field], [value] and [conditionType]. By this triplet in my example I have set that the filter be based on the `customer_id` and that it should try to match it (using:`eq`) to value `2`

Another example

http://yourdomain/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=customer_email&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=myname@gmail.com&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq

Here, the query is to look for a customer by email. `field` is set to `customer_email`, `value` to `myname@gmail.com` and `conditionType` to `eq`

You can, of course, do combinations of multiple filters and logical AND, and logical OR are possible for different fields.

This link gives even more details

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/use-rest/performing-searches/

I hope this helps.

Comment: iam using 


`http://www.depoto.com/Beta/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=customer_email&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=test@gmail.com`




it works fine

Comment: Do you know how to get wish list of specific user in magento 2 REST API

Comment: It's hard for me to believe as well, but the Wishlist module has no web api at all. This link show what is available per module https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/rest_endpoints.html. So, you will need to build your own service to query for wishlist items.

Comment: Remember to add the admin auth token on the request. And also note that this doesn't work for a customer's token.